# Как синхронизировать 2 потока с поочередным выполнением методов?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть 2 класса

```
class A : class Parent
{
    public void Draw()  
}

class B : class Parent
{
    public void Draw()  
}
```

И необходимо синхронизировать эти 2 потока, чтобы методы выполнялись строго поочередно. (или хотя бы до конца)
У класса Parent есть объект синхронизации. 
Метод Draw реализован примерно так

```
public void Draw()
{
    while(true)
    {
        lock(obj)
        {
            //Рисуем объект
        }
    }
}
```

Как мне казалось, потоки должны были выполняться пусть и не поочередно, но до конца, только после этого , должен был начаться другой поток (или этот же). По факту получается, что процессы друг другу мешают

```
class Parent 
{
    public object obj = new object();
}
```

Класс с потоками:

```
class Game
{
    public void Start()
    {
        A first = new A();
        B second = new B();

        Thread doRoad = new Thread(A.Draw);
        Thread doAuto = new Thread(B.Draw);

        A.Start();
        B.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: А где у вас в коде потоки?

Comment: И что такое `obj`? Это важно.

Comment: В другом классе. Создается 2 потока и там же стартуют.

Comment: Тогда покажите этот код. Ошибка должна быть там.

Comment: это полу родительского класса
    object obj = new object();

Comment: Это важно, добавьте это в вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из дискуссии в комментариях выяснилось, что у каждого из объектов свой экземпляр `obj`. Поэтому синхронизации и нету: ведь разные объекты синхронизируются каждый по своему `obj`!

Сделайте `obj` статическим полем базового класса.

Comment: Да , точно, упустил этот момент. Спасибо большое

Comment: @MikhailZnak: Пожалуйста!